# Sum of digits recurrence

Tags: number-theory

> The first number in a sequence is $7$. The next one we obtain as follows: we compute the square of the previous number $7^2 = 49$, then compute the sum of the digits of this square and increase it by $1$, i.e. the second number is $4+9+1 = 14$. We repeat this procedure to get $14^2 = 196$, and the third number of the sequence, which is $1+9+6+1 = 17$, and so on. What would be the $1999$th number in this sequence?

The sequence can be defined as $a_1 = 7$ and $a_{n+1} = s(a_n^2)+1$ where $s(n)$ denotes the sum of the digits of a positive integer $n$ and we want to find $a_{1999}$. I didn't see how to use the sequence to find this term.

Comment: Is there any context for this problem?  It seems quite arbitrary.  Absent context, I suppose I'd start by computing out a lot of terms.  Maybe it's periodic, for example.  How far have you computed?

Comment: @lulu It's from a math olympiad. I found the terms $7,14,17,20,5,8,11,5,8,11\ldots$.

Comment: Looks like my guess was correct.  It's periodic.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is: 7,14,17,20,5,8,11,5,... and now you see it repeats with a period of 3. In particular, we have  $a_{3k+1}=11$ for $k>1$, and so $a_{1999}=a_{3*666+1}=11$

Answer (score 0):

If you observe first few terms we get a pattern after some terms. The terms are $7,14,17,20,5,8,11,5,8,11.. $ from here you can tell what is $a_{1999} $ as $5,8,11$ are repeating.